# eyes will not parent to armature and animation

Tags: mesh, armature

[image]

Trying to add eye but they will not stay on character any advice?

Comment: It might be helpful to users if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

Comment: it looks like some vertices of your eye mesh have not been assigned to the good group, do it in Weight Paint mode or select them, choose the good group in the Vertex Groups list and click on Assign